# How do I do this calculation most efficiently with scipy sparse matrices?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have the following:

- A complex-valued sparse matrix Q (and its conjugate transpose is Q^H)
- A complex-valued diagonal matrix D
- A real-valued sparse vector v

and I wish to compute as efficiently as possible, using `scipy` sparse matrices, the product

Q @ (D @ (Q^H @ v)),

where the @s are matrix-vector multiplication and the bracketed order is chosen to avoid matrix-matrix multiplication. I am new to use of sparse matrices, and the available types confuse me. How would I best compute this in `scipy`? In particular, I'm wondering:

- Is it inefficient to mix matrix types? (e.g. would it be inefficient if Q were a CSC matrix and v were a CSR matrix - is there any general requirement for them all to be the same?)
- For each of Q, D, and v, which `scipy` sparse representation would be best to do efficient matrix-vector multiplication?
- If I were to port the code to run on my GPU using `cupy`, are there any additional factors I'd need to consider for efficiency?

Comment: Efficiency questions best answered by doing your own time tests on the alternatives.  In some SO I've discovered that when doing `A@A.T`, where `A` is `csr`, `A.T` is then `csc`, and the `@` converts that `csc` back to `csr`.  For squarish matrices the conversion between types is not a problem.  But for `(1,large_n)` shape, the `csc` format requires a lot more memory (the `indptr` is (large_n+1,) shpe).

Comment: The outer layers of the the `@` calls are Python, and can be examined.  So you can see for yourself where it converts format, from to csr to csc and v.v.  You can also check the matrix attributes yourself, the `indptr`, `indices`, and `data`.  I haven't explored the computational efficiency of various matrix@matrix and matric@vector combinations.  `vector` in the scipy sparse just means a (1,n) or (n,1) shape.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` is not a subclass of `numpy`, so I wouldn't expect that same sort of conversion to CUPY.  The attributes are numpy arrays, but the actual matrix multiplication uses compiled code - either it's own `cython` code, or a sparse package like `mkl`.